# Docker elasticsearch 1.7 executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a docker container for elasticsearch 1.7. Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip vim software-properties-common \
    && echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer \
    && wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/1.7/debian stable main" |  tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-1.7.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y elasticsearch \
    && echo "network.host: localhost" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml


EXPOSE 9200

CMD ["elasticsearch"]
```

Docker build works fine. But the **docker run** command is giving me this error: **Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"elasticsearch\": executable file not found in $PATH"**

I am using Mac and Docker version is: 17.09.0-ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a few days old - did you resolve it? The error message says exactly what the issue is (although I'm unsure why it's an issue).

I did a docker build based on this. Here's the `$PATH`:

```
root@96f969e3ab3d:/# echo $PATH
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Here's where elasticsearch gets installed (apparently):

```
root@96f969e3ab3d:/# find / -name 'elasticsearch' -type f
> /etc/default/elasticsearch
> /etc/init.d/elasticsearch
> /usr/share/lintian/overrides/elasticsearch
> /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
```

Based on that, it looks like elasticsearch gets installed at `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`. I think the easiest solution is to set the `CMD` to that full path:

```
CMD ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch"]
```

That being said, elasticsearch has a lot of other data it needs - just running that command doesn't appear to work. Based on [how complex their dockerfile](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/blob/6.1/templates/Dockerfile.j2) is, and based on what I'm seeing in the the `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` (which is how elasticsearch would run if installed on a server instead of within a container), I'm going to recommend using their official container instead of attempting to build your own.